# Missing Configure button in the Select Wallpaper From popup

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm programming a live wallpaper.
I've problem with the "**Configure...**" button in the **Select Wallpaper From** popup.
When user clicks to Menu in launcher, then selects the "Wallpaper" button, android shows a popup with these options: Gallery, Live Wallpapers, Wallpaper gallery.
If user has actually selected any Live wallpaper, there is an additional item in the popup: Configure..., which allows user to go to wallpaper's preferences directly.

I think that I've properly configured the android:settingsActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="something"
    android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon"
    android:description="something"
    android:settingsActivity="com.android.MyLiveWallpaper.Prefs">
</wallpaper>
```

The problem:
Everything works on my Samsung Galaxy S. I have the "Settings..." next to "Set wallpaper" button, when user selects my wallpaper. There is also the "**Configure...**" button in the **Select Wallpaper From** popup.
When I installed the wallpaper to the **Optimus LG One** phone, the **Configure...** button is not there. So user should go to walpapers list, select again my wallpaper to access the Settings.. button.
Both phones have running the same version of android os - Froyo 2.2.

Please, Is there any other think which I missed, so the LG Optimus One doesn't add the **Configure...** button to the **Select Wallpaper From** popup?

Answer (score 0):

The configure button os not a standard Android feature.

It also does not trigger the necessary callbacks once the user is done tweaking the settings.

So please use caution when relying on the Configure... button.